# Optimizing using R

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization

The data is:

```
name <- c("Gen1","Gen2","Gen3")

QuantityE <- c(200,100,50)

PriceE <- c(10,12,50)

QuantityAS <- c(100,50,10)

PriceAS <- c(1,5,7)

mydata <- data.frame(name, QuantityE, PriceE , QuantityAS,PriceAS )
```

I have the following objective function:

Minimize total cost when  multiplying combinations of

```
((PriceE*QuantityE) + (PriceAS* QuantityAS))
```

Subject to constraints:

```
Total QuantityE = 300

Total QuantityAS = 0.06* QuantityE
```

What is the best approach to use, or what I can read up to solve the problem?

Comment: As written it is a bit difficult to understand what you need help on. Are you familiar with linear programming or are you asking for help formulating the linear program? If you are familiar, are you aware of R linear programming packages like lpSolve? Have you made any coding attempts with these packages?

Comment: This seems linear. Use linear programming: https://www.r-bloggers.com/linear-programming-in-r-an-lpsolveapi-example/

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, after some reading, found the right way to code the LP.
There is neater ways of doing it, but this works for me.

```
name <- c("Gen1","Gen2","Gen3")
QuantityE <- c(200,100,50)
PriceE <- c(10,12,50)
QuantityAS <- c(100,50,10)
PriceAS <- c(1,5,7)
mydata <- data.frame(name, QuantityE, PriceE , QuantityAS,PriceAS ) 

#System Data
EnergyDemand <- 300 #Total QuantityE
CRRequired <- 0.06*EnergyDemand #Total Quantity AS

library(lpSolve)
#Set up Objective function, prices will be the co-ef's
obj.fun <- as.vector(stack(mydata[,c(3,5)])[1])

##Set up the constraints matrix
#This will set up individual quantityE and quantityAS coef's
D <- diag(1, NROW(obj.fun),NROW(obj.fun))

#This sets up coefficients with the ability to combine QuantityAS and QuantityE 
E <- diag(1, NROW(name),NROW(name))
FA <- cbind(E,E)

#This sets up the cofficients for all quantityE
G <- matrix(c(rep(1,NROW(name)),rep(0,NROW(name))),1)

#This sets up the cofficients for all quantityAS
H <- matrix(c(rep(0,NROW(name)),rep(1,NROW(name))),1)

#This combines the above constraints into one matrix
constr <- rbind(D,FA,G,H)

#Set up directional constraints. All except the last 2 are <=
#This allows flexibility in choosing volumes
# The last two have to be equal to for Energy and AS demand
constr.dir <- c(rep("<=",NROW(constr)-2), rep("=",2))

#This sets up the rhs numbers for the matrix above
rhs <- c(QuantityE, QuantityAS, pmax(QuantityE, QuantityAS), EnergyDemand,CRRequired)

#This is the algorithm parameters
prod.sol <- lp("min", obj.fun, constr, constr.dir, rhs, compute.sens = TRUE)

a <- matrix(prod.sol$solution, nrow= length(name)) #decision variables values 
rownames(a) <- name
colnames(a) <- c("Energy MW", "AS MW")

#This is the Summary of results
print(mydata) #This gives the initial dataset
a # This gives the combination of quantity used from Gen's
prod.sol #This gives the optimal minimized cost
```